# Where do I put my mapping logic?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, datamapper

I have a domain model, a repository and entity framework. I don't want my domain tied to EF or the persistence layer in general.

So I created a repository to keep things like `db.Users.Where(u => u.Team == "MyTeam")` out of my domain.

After implementing the generic repository pattern if I want a list of users on a particular team I use `UserRepository.GetUsersByTeam("MyTeam")`.

The problem is my UserRepository is returning `IEnumerable<EntityFrameworkUser>`, instead of `IEnumerable<DomainUser>`, and in order to return `IEnumerable<DomainUser>` I need to map `DomainUser` to `EntityFrameworkUser` somewhere.

So where specifically do you map from the EntityFrameworkUser class to the DomainUser class?

Should the repository encapsulate the mapping logic in addition to the query logic?

If I want a collection of domain user objects what does the call stack look like for `UserRepository.GetUsersByTeam("MyTeam")` look like?

Searching has only found me general responses that usually quote Martin Fowler. I need a concrete example to refer to.

Comment: Maybe this should be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com because it's whiteboard-y?

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is my UserRepository is returning an entity framework User DbSet

That shouldn't be the return type, because that would introduce coupling.  You can still *return* that type, but it should be polymorphically interpreted as a different type.

So while you may be doing something like this in your repository:

```
return db.Users;
```

The *return type* shouldn't be that implementing type (`DbSet<User>`?), but something more generic:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
{
    return db.Users;
}
```

The "EF objects" are being used throughout the domain, but the domain doesn't know or care about that.  The domain sees it as a queryable collection of `User` models.

Comment: I've updated the question for clarity. I'm returning IEnumerable<EntityFrameworkUser>, not the DbSet.

Comment: @Legion: Do you have *two* different `User` types?  One for EF and one for the domain?  It sounds like you're using EF fundamentally incorrectly in that case.  EF should be persisting your domain objects.

Comment: Yes I have two. One (for EF) is for the persistence layer and maps 1 to 1 to the database. The other (for domain) contains all my business logic and is not a mirror of the database's User table.

Comment: @Legion: If you *must* have two then the mapping logic would *definitely* belong in the persistence layer, since it's bound to the database structure.  The only outwardly-visible types from your repository interfaces should be domain types.  But I highly recommend trying to simply use EF to persist your domain models where possible.

Comment: The problem with that is what happens when I want to switch to nHibernate, or a web service? All my business logic is directly bound to entity framework.

Comment: @Legion: What makes you think that?  Your business logic belongs in the domain models, and the repository interfaces have only domain types.  You can implement those interfaces with any technology you like.

Comment: @Legion: You might find an old example of mine useful: http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/persistence-ignorance-with-entity.html  The idea there is to start with the domain models, keeping them entirely persistence-ignorant, and then build an isolated EF-based data layer to persist them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep domain object separately - keep them separately. If you repository returns objects from persistent layer, then it opens door for [over-posting](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/01/31/web-security-in-mvc4-net4-5-with-c-mass-assignment-aka-overposting/) issues (it especially dangerous when front-end uses the same objects). I would move mapping logic into another class and use it in your repositories.

[Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is very popular library for mapping different object, for example Domain object to DTO and vise versa. You can inject Automapper into your repositories and use it to map `IEnumerable<EntityFrameworkUser>` to `IEnumerable<DomainUser>`. First register mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityFrameworkUser, DomainUser>();
```

Then call it from your repository

```
return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EntityFrameworkUser>, IEnumerable<DomainUser>>(users);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the purpose of the method in question is simply to always return all of the members of the specified team, and you're never going to apply additional clauses to the result, you could change the return type of the `UserRepostory.GetUsersByTeam()` method from the EF `DbSet<User>` type to `List<User>`, then change the return statement to `return db.Users.Where(u => u.Team == "MyTeam").ToList()`.

You'll no longer get the EF objects out of the repository level.

Comment: This would materialize *the entire list* every time, nullifying the point of deferred querying of the resulting enumeration.  So if anybody ever calls `GetUsersByTeam()` and appends another clause to it, say filtering down to a single user, it's still going to fetch *every* user from the database for that team.

Comment: It sounds to me like the purpose of the `GetUsersByTeam` method is to return every user in the team, and that's what you'd expect it to return. Of course, this is only one example.